# Disable Shift+Delete

Tags: windows

How can I disable <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> so that even if the key combination is used the files always get to the Recycle Bin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't really a way to do this. You can disable it in particular applications, for example there is a registry hack to prevent it in Outlook, however I do not know of any for Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 10):

You could use something like [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to map <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> to <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

However, you would need AutoHotKey running all the time for this to work.

The AutoHotKey script to do this is as follows:

```
+Delete::
KeyWait Shift
Send {Delete}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to guarantee that files end up in the Recycle Bin.  Some files are too large.  Or a user might delete too many files and a file that was recently deleted gets evicted right away.  Technically that file went to the Recycle Bin but for practical purposes it did not.  The TweakUI Powertoy lets you customize certain key-bindings but Shift-Delete isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the shift key under the enter key (I assume that's the one that's being used for this operation). Keep the left shift for actually doing capital letters etc. Maybe a little over the top... but you never know- might be something that will work for you.